# Set values for two fields using single select in php

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

My programming skills as you will see are very limited. I have the following code inside a file in a component administrator in Joomla backend.

```
<div class="detail_box">
<div  class="form-detail req"></div>
<label for="vathmos_ptyxiou"><?php echo JText::_('Βαθμός πτυχίου')?></label> 
<?php if( $this->item->vathmos_ptyxiou == 'Καλώς') { ?> 
<select name="vathmos_ptyxiou"><option value="Καλώς"  selected="selected">Καλώς</option><option value="Λίαν Καλώς">Λίαν Καλώς</option><option value="Άριστα">Άριστα</option></select>
<?php } elseif( $this->item->vathmos_ptyxiou == 'Λίαν Καλώς') { ?> 
                        <select name="vathmos_ptyxiou"><option value="Καλώς">Καλώς</option><option value="Λίαν Καλώς" selected="selected">Λίαν Καλώς</option><option value="Άριστα">Άριστα</option></select>
<?php } elseif( $this->item->vathmos_ptyxiou == 'Άριστα') { ?> 
                        <select name="vathmos_ptyxiou"><option value="Καλώς">Καλώς</option><option value="Λίαν Καλώς">Λίαν Καλώς</option><option value="Άριστα" selected="selected">Άριστα</option></select>
<?php } else {?>
<select name="vathmos_ptyxiou"><option value="Καλώς">Καλώς</option><option value="Λίαν Καλώς" >Λίαν Καλώς</option><option value="Άριστα">Άριστα</option></select>
<?php } ?>

<div class="clear"></div>
<span class="error_msg" id="frmdidaktoriko_error_msg" style="display: none;"><?php echo JText::_('LNG_REQUIRED_FIELD')?></span>
</div>
```

Here when I press save the DB field vathmos_ptyxiou gets the value that the user has selected. Everything is good 
NOW I created a field vath_ptyxiou (varchar 200 with NULL allowed) into the db (mySql) and what I want to do is when the value of vathmos_ptyxiou is "Άριστα" vath_ptyxiou should get the value of lets say 3000.
I added the following php code:

```
<?php if ( $this->item->vathmos_ptyxiou == 'Άριστα') {$this->item->vath_ptyxiou = 3000; ?> <?php } echo $this->item->vath_ptyxiou; ?>
```

On the form it echoes 3000 but the vath_ptyxiou field is still NULL. It doesn't get any value.
What is the correct way to insert the value of 3000 into the vath_ptyxiou field when someone selects "Άριστα"? This doesn't need to be "On the fly" I need this when someone presses save on the form.
Thank you in advance

Comment: This is just display code. There's nothing in here about interfacing with the database where the problem presumably lies.

Comment: From what I know depending on the selection someone makes the field vathmos_ptyxiou gets updated (changes) into the database. i.e. if someone selects "Καλώς" then the field vathmos_ptyxiou for that record gets the value of "Καλώς". If the "Λίαν Καλώς" gets selected when I press save the value "Λίαν Καλώς" gets into the field vathmos_ptyxiou etc....

Comment: It'd be easier to follow what you're saying if you replaced the Greek with A, B, C or whatever and strip out anything not strictly related to the problem at hand, but that's not the real issue. There's no database code here, so I'm not sure where the problem is. This is exclusively display code, no updates occur in what you've shown.

Comment: do you have any Table class that extends JTable in `administrator/components/com_XXX/tables/XXX.php` ?

Comment: Thinking that the db field vathmos_ptyxiou must be defined somewhere else what I did is was to search all of joomla structure to see if there is an occurrence of vathmos_ptyxiou but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: I see that there is a function defined inside the same file :       function saveCompanyInformation() {
 if(validateCmpForm())
  return false;
  jQuery("#task").val('managecompany.save');
  jQuery("#selectedSubcategories").each(function(){ 
  jQuery("#selectedSubcategories option").attr("selected","selected"); 
 });
 var form = document.adminForm;
 form.submit();
 }
But I don't see any variables here or something that has to do with inserting into the DB...

Comment: Should I post the whole file? How can I do that?

Comment: Yes there are different files inside administrator/components/com_jbusinessdirectory/tables/ There is also the file company.php but I don't see any db fields there... What should I search for?

Comment: ANYONE???? What should I search for?

Comment: I finally got it to work....I used :  <?php if ( $this->item->vathmos_ptyxiou == 'Άριστα') {?> <input type="text" name="vath_ptyxiou" id="vath_ptyxiou" style="display: none;" value="<?php echo $this->item->vath_ptyxiou?>"> <?php } echo $this->item->vath_ptyxiou; ?>
What it does is inserts a value to vath_ptyxiou like it does for other fields in the code in a text field and it hides it. I just need to know if this efficient. Can you please let me know? Thanks